# Resumable Upload to Google CLoud Storage using Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

Ive been testing resumable upload of a file (500MB) to google cloud storage using python but it doesn't seem to be working.

As per the official documentation(https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#python): *Resumable uploads occur when the object is larger than 8 MiB, and multipart uploads occur when the object is smaller than 8 MiB This threshold cannot be changed. The Python client library uses a buffer size that's equal to the chunk size. 100 MiB is the default buffer size used for a resumable upload, and you can change the buffer size by setting the blob.chunk_size property.*

This is the python code Ive written to test resumable upload

```
def upload_to_bucket(blob_name, path_to_file, bucket_name):
"""Upload a file to the bucket"""

storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(RAW_DATA_BUCKET_PERMISSIONS_FILEPATH)

bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

blob.upload_from_filename(path_to_file)
```

The time to upload the file using this function took about 84s.  I then deleted the file and then re-ran this function, but cut-off my internet connection after about 40s.  After establishing internet connection again, i re-ran the upload function expecting the upload time to be much shorter, instead it took the about 84s again.

Is this how resumable upload is suppose to work?

We have field units in remote locations with spotty cellular connection running raspberry pis. We have issues getting data out sometimes.  This data is about 0.2-1MB in size.  Having a resumable solution that works with small file sizes, and doesn't have to try and upload the whole file each time after an initial failure would be great.

Perhaps there is a better way?  Thanks for any help, Rich :)

Comment: Check the status of your resumable upload. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#resume-upload

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the documentation is trying to say that the client will, within that one function call, resume an upload in the event of a transient network failure. It does not mean that if you re-run the program and attempt to upload the same file to the same blob name a second time, that the client library will be able to detect your previous attempt and resume the operation.

In order to resume an operation, you'll need a session ID for an upload session. You can create one by calling blob.[create_resumable_upload_session](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_create_resumable_upload_session)(). That'll get you a URL which you can upload data or query for recorded progress on the server. You'll need to save it somewhere your program will notice it on the next run.

You can either use an HTTP utility to do a PUT directly to the URL, or you could use the [ResumableUpload](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/google-resumable-media/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.ResumableUpload) class of the `google-resumable-media` package to manage the upload to that URL for you.

Comment: Thanks Brandon.  That makes sense now.  However, I'm still a little confused how you resume an interrupted upload on the next run using this URL.  There is little info out there that demonstrates how this is done.  Currently Im adding the resumable upload url to the ResumableUpload class.   If i don't initiate the upload an exception is thrown (his upload has not been initiated. Please call initiate() before beginning to transmit chunks.)  If i do initiate the upload, it says resume incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

There is little info out there that demonstrates how this is done.  This is how i ended up getting it to work.  I'm sure there is a better way so let me know

```
def upload_to_bucket(blob_name, path_to_file, bucket_name):
"""Upload a file to the bucket"""

upload_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{bucket_name}/o?uploadType=resumable&name={blob_name}"

file_total_bytes = os.path.getsize(path_to_file)
print('total bytes of file ' + str(file_total_bytes))

# intiate a resumable upload session
upload = ResumableUpload(upload_url, CHUNK_SIZE)

# provide authentication
transport = AuthorizedSession(credentials=CLIENT._credentials)

metadata={'name': blob_name}

with open(path_to_file, "rb") as file_to_transfer:

    response = upload.initiate(transport, file_to_transfer, metadata, 'application/octet-stream', total_bytes=file_total_bytes)

    print('Resumable Upload URL ' + response.headers['Location'])

    # save resumable url to json file in case there is an issue
    add_resumable_url_to_file(path_to_file, upload.resumable_url)
    
    while True:
        try:
            response = upload.transmit_next_chunk(transport)

            if response.status_code == 200:
                #upload complete
                break
            if response.status_code != 308:
                # save Resumable URL and try next time
                raise Exception('Failed to upload chunk')
            print(upload.bytes_uploaded)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            
    print('cloud upload complete')
    
remove_resumable_url_from_file(path_to_file)
```

def resume_upload_to_bucket(resumable_upload_url, path_to_file,):

```
# check resumable upload status
response = requests.post(resumable_upload_url, timeout=60)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Resumable upload completed successfully')
    remove_resumable_url_from_file(path_to_file)
    return

# get the amount of bytes previously uploaded
previous_amount_bytes_uploaded = int(response.headers.get('Range', '0').split('-')[-1]) + 1
file_total_bytes = os.path.getsize(path_to_file)

with open(path_to_file, "rb") as file_to_transfer:

    # Upload the remaining data
    for i in range(previous_amount_bytes_uploaded, file_total_bytes, CHUNK_SIZE):
        # chunk = file_to_transfer[i:i + CHUNK_SIZE]
        file_byte_location = file_to_transfer.seek(i)
        print(file_byte_location)
        chunk = file_to_transfer.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        headers = {'Content-Range': f'bytes {i}-{i + len(chunk) - 1}/{file_total_bytes}'}
        response = requests.put(resumable_upload_url, data=chunk, headers=headers, timeout=60)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            #upload complete
            break
        if response.status_code != 308:
            # save Resumable URL and try next time
            raise Exception('Failed to upload chunk')
        

print('resumable upload completed')
remove_resumable_url_from_file(path_to_file)
```