# Python Google storage Range headert always starts at 0

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to upload a very big file (10GB) to google storage with resumable upload. As described here
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#chunked-upload

I receive the `Range` header but it always starts at 0  eg. `0-176160767`.
My 'Content-Range' header is as it is described in the docs also, and looks like this `bytes 167772160-176160767/10968242348`.

After some time the upload stops and the file is not uploaded, there is no 200 response code no 400-500 response codes either, only the last response code 308 and then stop. What is causing this behaviour?

This is the code I'm trying to accomplish this with, as described in this question [Resumable Upload to Google CLoud Storage using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75330321/resumable-upload-to-google-cloud-storage-using-python):

```
import requests

CHUNK_SIZE = 8388608

response = requests.post(resumable_upload_url, timeout=60)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Resumable upload completed successfully')
    remove_resumable_url_from_file(path_to_file)
    return

# get the amount of bytes previously uploaded
previous_amount_bytes_uploaded = int(response.headers.get('Range', '0').split('-')[-1]) + 1
file_total_bytes = os.path.getsize(path_to_file)

with open(path_to_file, "rb") as file_to_transfer:
    for i in range(previous_amount_bytes_uploaded, file_total_bytes, CHUNK_SIZE):
        # chunk = file_to_transfer[i:i + CHUNK_SIZE]
        file_byte_location = file_to_transfer.seek(i)
        print(file_byte_location)
        chunk = file_to_transfer.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        headers = {'Content-Range': f'bytes {i}-{i + len(chunk) - 1}/{file_total_bytes}'}
        response = requests.put(resumable_upload_url, data=chunk, headers=headers, timeout=60)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            break
        if response.status_code != 308:
            # save Resumable URL and try next time
            print(response.headers.get("Range"))
            raise Exception('Failed to upload chunk')
```

Comment: response code 308  - Resume Incomplete Indicates an incomplete resumable upload and provides the range of bytes already received by Cloud Storage.check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-status#308%E2%80%94resume-incomplete)